# GPIO is deactivated by loudspeaker

Tags: gpio, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, pi-b

I use https://github.com/ts1/PiIR to send - pin 22 - and receive - pin 23 - infrared signals

This works fine as long as I don't play anything through the speaker connected to the pi's own jack socket, as long as I don't play anything, for example via aplay.

As soon as I send infrared signals after playback, they are not transmitted, instead I hear a noise* from the loudspeaker. A reboot solves the problem until I play something again.

What can be the reason for this?

*Here is an audio sample in a zip file (only for those extra courageous who dare to open a zip file and CAUTION, it....downloads right away, hope that won't give you nightmares ) see https://forum-raspberrypi.de/attachment/36932-221211-8109-zip

Comment: This question is lacking detail of WHAT YOU DID or what services the program uses. Including a link that automatically downloads a file is unacceptable.

Comment: At a first guess you are trying to use something which uses PWM which is used by audio.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ts1/PiIR uses pigpio to send the IR messages.

In this particular usage audio using GPIO will not be available.

(pigpio uses one of the PWM/PCM audio blocks for internal sampling purposes and the other free PWM/PCM audio block to transmit the IR signal)

Comment: What is the solution then?

Comment: Don't use pigpio or use a USB audio solution are the obvious ones.